# Create object with no self casting shadows, but can cast and receive shadows in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, materials, objects, eevee-render-engine, shadows

How do I create an object with no self casting shadows, but can cast and receive shadows in Eevee? (See image. Green: good! Red: Bad!)

In the example, the object on the left has a normal node connected and it's shadow mode turned to none. The object on the right is just a duplicate with shadow mode on opaque.

[image: Example picture]